# CSS a:hover keep original color

Tags: css

Is it possible to keep the color on a link with a class while other links do change.

For example I have a theme but i want it to support different colors set by the user.

Most links change color on :hover but some must stay the same color.

#red is generated by the theme. I want to 'inherit' the `a.someclass:link` color in the `a.someclass:hover`

example:

```
a:link
{
  color: #red;
}
a:hover {
  color: #black;
}
```

The above part is generated which I cannot alter.

As suggested in answers and comments below I need to build this with jQuery

sure I can copy #red to the `a.someclass:hover {}` but then i have to hardcode the color and since the user should be able to change the color that is not an option.

I need something to overide the `a:hover { color }` if the class is someclass

Comment: I think you need to use JS to do this.

Comment: I asked a similar question just now but pushed for a CSS solution and someone provided one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401942/css-color-anchor-but-not-ahover

Comment: So if I understand you right I can just do: `a.someclass:hover { color:inherit }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @danferth and @maxisam here is my jQuery solution
I've written to make this work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // getting the color before the color is changed ( not sure this is needed )
  var thecolor = $('.article-title').css("color");
  $(".article-title").mouseover(function() {
    // setting the color previously picked
    $(this).css({'color':thecolor});
  });       
});
```

where .article-title is the class of the links I want to alter

Answer (score 18):

You can make use of [`currentColor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#Currentcolor_example)

```
a.no-color-change:hover {
  color: currentColor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this then?

```
a:link, a.someclass:hover
{
  color: #red;
}
```

At least if I understand your question correctly.. This will make sure both your `<a>` tags will have the same color as the `<a class="someclass">` ones when hovered.

Comment: as I explained in my question the code for a:link is generated so I can not change any code there. If that was the case it would be simple ;)

Answer (score 1):

Like maxisam said above you will probably have to use `js` to do this.  Try using `jQuery`'s `.hover()` or `.mouseover()` `.mouseout()` to change the `css`. You would of course have to trigger these functions somehow when the user switches themes.  Good luck.